# Ceiling fan issues

Tags: electrical

Ok a while back I had asked about my ceiling fan not being able to come on or spin very slow. I have a lot of responses saying that my capacitor had failed. So I replaced my capacitor and I am STILL having the same issue. The ceiling fan will come on and spin,  but at a very slow speed. I had matched my capacitor exactly like the old one.
So my question is could the issue be in the fan speed switch or possibly with the motor?

Comment: Does this fan have a wireless remote or is it just controlled by a pull chain?

Comment: Nothing wireless. Just by a pull chain and wall switch

Comment: What brand and model of fan is this?

Comment: Royal Pacific ceiling fan

Comment: Is the wall switch a speed control or just a wall switch?

Comment: Just a wall switch